# Tangents to two sets

Tags: tangent-line

Find all the affine tangents that are simultaneously tangent to the set $E$ and $H$: $$H=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:xy=-5\}, E=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R^2:\frac{x^2}{9}+\frac{y^2}{4}=1\}$$

I know that when the line is tangent to the set A at point a: $T_aA=\{v:<grad(h(a)),v>=0\}$ but I don't know how to combine this condition for both sets $ E, H $ to find all tangents

Comment: Do you know what are those sets, to begin with?

Comment: @IvanNeretin yes - ellipse and hyperbola

Comment: Good. Now, how many common tangents are there, what do you think?

Comment: @IvanNeretin I think $2$

Answer (score 1):

Any tangent to the given ellipse is $$y=mx \pm \sqrt{9m^2+4}$$, insert this in the Eq. of hyperbola:$xy=-5$, to get
$$mx^2+\pm\sqrt{9m^2+4}x+5=0$$
For tangency we impose $B^2=4AC$, Then
$$9m^2+4=20m \implies m=2, 2/9$$
The tangents are $$y=2x\pm 2\sqrt{10},~~ y=2x/9\pm2\sqrt{10}/3.$$

[image]

Comment: @kp123 For any real value of $m$, it is tangent to the given ellipse.

Comment: It is well know: let $y=mx+c$ be the tangent to x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2=1, put the line in ellipse to get a quadratic of $x$. There you demand single root by imposing $B^2=4AC$  you get $c=\pm \sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}$. Hence $y=mx \pm \sqrt{a^2m^2+b^2}$ always tangent to this ellipse for any real value of $m$.